# Passing nodes as parameters to a macro in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, parameters

I would like to define a macro which would take two nodes as arguments and
"connect" them using a third, predefined node. Like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}

\newcommand{\diamondconn}[3]{
  \node[diamond, draw, innter sep=2pt] (diamond) { #1 };
  % get the references to #2 and #3 and position them
  % on the left and right side of the `conn' node
}

\begin{document}

% instead of writing this...
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[diamond, draw, inner sep=2pt] (diamond) { conn };
  \node[draw, left=0pt of diamond.west] { foo };
  \node[draw, circle, right=0pt of diamond.east] { bar };
\end{tikzpicture}

% I would like to write this:
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \diamondconn{conn}{
    \node[draw, rectangle] { foo };
  }{
    \node[draw, circle] { bar };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I know I could do it backwards, i.e. define a macro for the connecting node
and insert it when needed, I am just curious if the first option is possible
as well.

Comment: I you would write it as `\diamondconn{conn}{[draw, rectangle] { foo }}{[draw, circle] { bar }}`, you could then use `\node [left=0pt of diamond.west] #2; \node [right=0pt of diamond.east] #3; `. The `\node` should support double options.

Comment: @Martin: Shouldn't this be an answer?

Comment: @Jake: Yeah, I wasn't sure if I understood the OP correctly. I might want to use the full `\node ... ;` syntax. Also I'm at the rep cap for today anyway ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to keep the node definitions you pass as arguments independent of what happens inside the macro (so you don't want to explicitly use `left of=diamond.west` in the node definition). In order to achieve this, you can wrap the nodes passed in `scope` environments inside the macro and "inject" the positioning options, or, as Martin Scharrer suggests, use `\tikzset` inside curly braces to set the options locally:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}

\newcommand{\diamondconn}[3]{

  \node[diamond, draw, inner sep=2pt] (diamond) { #1 };
  {\tikzset{every node/.style={left=0pt of diamond.west}} #2 }
  {\tikzset{every node/.style={right=0pt of diamond.east}} #3 } 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \diamondconn{conn}{
    \node[draw, rectangle] { foo };
  }{
    \node[draw, circle] { bar };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree. You could also use `{\tikzset{every node/.style={...}} #2}` etc. if you want to avoid the `scope`. But it should be `.append style` anyway, otherwise existing settings will be overwritten. (Also, please don't use the `minimal` class for minimal example, even when the name sounds like it.)

Comment: @Martin: Sorry about the `minimal` class, I missed that when I copied the MWE. Good point about the `\tikzset`, that's definitely less tedious. Two things about the `.style`/`.append style`: 1. In this case, wouldn't you *want* to overwrite options, e.g. if for some reason the nodes passed as arguments contain a different positioning option? 2. It seems neither `.style` nor `.append style` actually manage to overwrite an option in this setup (I tried changing the shape of the first node, and it had no effect).

Comment: I meant that `every node/.style` will overwrite an "global" `every node/.style`, e.g. if you use `\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={outer sep=5pt,blue}]` then this wouldn't be in effect for the two side nodes if you use `every node/.style`. You might not be able to overwrite the options passed to `\node` because `every node` might be executed before that options.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{minimal}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,fit}

\newcommand{\diamondconn}[3]{%    
  \node[diamond, draw, inner sep=2pt] (diamond) { #1 }; 
  #2#3 }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \diamondconn{conn}{
     \node[draw, left=0pt of diamond.west] { foo }; 
  }{%
   \node[draw, circle, right=0pt of diamond.east] { bar };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you only use `#2#3` in the macro then there is no reason to have the arguments in the first place.

Comment: I agree that my answer doesn't make sense but the question is very strange and I think to put `\node` in arguments doesn't make sense too.

Comment: I agree, having the full `\note` code in the argument is quite strange.